# How to count rows in a table (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am currently working on an attendance system using php and mysql and I want to count the number of Present/Absent/Late of that student, which is happened on the same table. Like for example the table looks like this.

```
student_name | attendance status |  date
             |                   |
student1     |  Present          |  2019-02-21
student2     |  Absent           |  2019-02-21
student3     |  Late             |  2019-02-21  
student1     |  Absent           |  2019-02-22
student2     |  Absent           |  2019-02-22
student3     |  Present          |  2019-02-22
```

I want output as below : Show how many presents/absents/late is a student in a month like

```
student 1    | 20 presents       |  4 absents   | 2 lates
```

I am using **fpdf library** but even a php code for that is a big help.

Table name : attendance_records

Solt'n

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "
                                SELECT student_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attendance = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS presents,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attendance = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absents,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attendance = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lates
FROM attendance_records
GROUP BY student_name
    ") or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));                                    
    foreach( $result as $row ) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',9);
    $pdf->Ln();     
      foreach($row as $column) {                                                                                                                                                           
    $pdf->Cell(39,10,$column,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a database front-end, it's not a programming language or database. How does it relate here?

Comment: oops. sorry sir, im just a beginner, my bad for that :)

Comment: Just clarifying some terminology. Nothing wrong with learning!

Comment: can you help me to this problem sir?

Comment: Even if you are a beginner: what have you tried so far? Try splitting the problems up into: a) getting the proper data using a query in phpMyAdmin, b) getting that data in PHP, c) writing that data to a PDF file - which of these parts are already finished?

Comment: sir @Nico, I've tried most of that but i know im doing something wrong hehe :) but i'll try studying the answer of sir mleko, Thank you for your concern sir

Comment: If you've **tried** something, share that with us. That enable us to understand where you went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to achieve what you need

Try using query

```
SELECT student_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attendance = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS presents,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attendance = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absents,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attendance = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lates
FROM attendance_records
GROUP BY student_name
```

Comment: Uhmm. Im going to be honest here sir, but can you please elaborate that sir. The fact that sum and case are foreign to me :) Thank you sir :)

Comment: You'll need to consult the reference material to fill in any gaps. [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) are fully documented.

Comment: can u try some codes over here sir? so i have some reference in doing so. Im having a hard time displaying the output

Comment: @Janrey You want to display this using PHP or phpMyAdmin? How do you connect to database? Show us what have you tried and where you stuck?

Comment: i want to display it as a pdf file but in order to do that i want to understand  on how it displays in php because by understanding that, it'll be easy for me to translate it to pdf.           i've tried this.

Comment: @Janrey If we managed to help you, share complete solutions so others can benefit from it in future

Comment: the complete solution is already at the edited post sir, i just tried to understand it and  came up with that solution

Answer (score -2):

Use in phpmyadmin ..

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE attendance_status = absent;

Phpmyadmin will count it automatically..

But you should code in php and mysql or mysqli ..

Comment: what i mean sir is per student, not all the datas .. (if im not wrong understading what you mean sir). btw, Thank you for responding :)

Comment: That query won't count anything

Comment: try this 


SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE attendance_status = absent AND student_name = student1;

I told you that you will get best result with php and mysqli or mysql

Comment: That other query won't count anything either